# How to fix strange loop iteration when using npm request-promise?

Tags: node.js, request-promise

I have been trying to get some data from a website into my NODE application using web-scraping. The data looks to work alright although there are strange operations in the for loop I have created.

ISSUES I'm facing:

1. Iterations are not sequential.
2. list.length starts from 1 and not 0, WHY?
3. Not all the data are added on the table.

So the code I'm using (see below), runs through a list of URL's, then I add them in an object called `options` and finally pass the option in the `request-promise` function. The first issue is that on one trial it will execute on this sequence 1, 2, 0 and on another trial it might execute 0, 2, 1. Since I access a server with a GET request I thought it would need time to load the data, so I have tried using `async` and `await` which didn't work. I have also tried `sleep` but also didn't work. The sequence remains unstable.

The second problem is that the length of the list doesn't start with 0 but on 1. (i.e. `let list = ["0", "1", "2", "3"]` would have length of 4). Is it by default in NODE?

The third issue is that even if all iterations are made (even in wrong sequence), SOMETIMES it would show less data than expected!

```
const listOfJobIds = ["MTM2NDQtMTE1NzQ2LVMgMQ", "MjI3MjkwIDU", "MjI3MjIzIDU"];
let listLength = listOfJobIds.length - 1;
let options = {};

function loopJobs(listOfJobIds) {

    for(let i=0; i<listOfJobIds.length; i++){
        //Declare options for the request-promise
        options = {
            url: 'https://ec.europa.eu/eures/eures-searchengine/page/jv/id/'+listOfJobIds[i]+'?lang=en&_=1594981312724&app=2.4.1-build-2',
            json: true
        }
        
        rp(options).then(
            async (data) => {

                await getJobInformation(data, i); 
            }
        ).catch(
            (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        );
    }    
}
loopJobs(listOfJobIds);

async function getJobInformation(data, i) {

    process.stdout.write('JOB: '+i+' - Loading JOB information ');

    //GET SOME DATA
    var language = data.jvProfiles[data.preferredLanguage];
    let job_id = data.id;
    process.stdout.write('. ');
    let job_vacancy_id = data.documentId;
    process.stdout.write('. ');
    let job_title = language.title;
    process.stdout.write('. ');
    let job_description = language.description;
    process.stdout.write('. ');
        
    //ADD INFORMATION IN THE TABLE
    job_table.push([
        job_id, 
        job_vacancy_id,
        job_title, 
        job_description
    ]);

    console.log("✅");
    
    if(i == listLength){
        printTable1();
    }
}
```

TRIAL 1:

```
JOB: 0 - Loading JOB information . . . . ✅
JOB: 2 - Loading JOB information . . . . ✅
┌──────────────┬──────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐       
│ Job ID       │ Job Vacancy ID   │ Job Title                              │ Job Description                                                      │       
├──────────────┼──────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤       
│ MTM2NDQtMTE… │ 13644-115746-S   │ SAP BASIS HANA Manager, Database Engi… │ Stellenangebotsbeschreibung: <br>Minimum qualifications:<br><br>- B… │       
├──────────────┼──────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤       
│ MjI3MjIzIDU  │ 227223           │ DATABASE ADMINISTRATION                │ -MANAGING DATABASES ON PREMISES AS WELL AS IN CLOUD -HANDLING MIGRA… │       
└──────────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘       
JOB: 1 - Loading JOB information . . . . ✅
```

TRIAL 2:

```
JOB: 2 - Loading JOB information . . . . ✅
┌──────────────┬──────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Job ID       │ Job Vacancy ID   │ Job Title                              │ Job Description                                                      │
├──────────────┼──────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ MjI3MjIzIDU  │ 227223           │ DATABASE ADMINISTRATION                │ -MANAGING DATABASES ON PREMISES AS WELL AS IN CLOUD -HANDLING MIGRA… │
└──────────────┴──────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
JOB: 1 - Loading JOB information . . . . ✅
JOB: 0 - Loading JOB information . . . . ✅
```

Comment: You are running all your requests in parallel and they finish in whatever order the server decides to complete them in which may not even be the same every time.  Are you intending to run your operations sequentially where the 2nd one doesn't start until the 1st one is done?

Comment: That what I thought, and tried waiting it to finish using `async` `await` `sleep`. But couldn't get it to work :/

Comment: Well, a proper implementation using `await` would work just fine so apparently you had mistakes in your implementation.  We can't help you fix that version of code that you haven't shown us.  From your other observations, it sounds like `getJobInformation()` may also contain some race conditions.

Comment: I don't in what order it will retrieve information, but I want all the results (3 in these case). Okay I will try work with it again, and also update my question

Comment: You should also include the code for `getJobInformation()` because part of the problem may be in that function.

Comment: I have updated my code, I have successfully added `async` `await` and there are no errors this time. But didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to sequence your calls to `getJobInformation()`, then you can do this:

```
async function loopJobs(listOfJobIds) {

    for (let i=0; i<listOfJobIds.length; i++){
        //Declare options for the request-promise
        let options = {
            url: 'https://ec.europa.eu/eures/eures-searchengine/page/jv/id/'+listOfJobIds[i]+'?lang=en&_=1594981312724&app=2.4.1-build-2',
            json: true
        }
        
        let data = await rp(options);
        await getJobInformation(data, i); 
    }    
    printTable1();     // I would suggest removing this call from getJobInformation()
}

loopJobs(listOfJobIds).then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

Note: `getJobInformation()` isn't a classic asynchronous function.  It writes to the stream which is somewhat asynchronous, but nothing in the function is being waited on and thus you are getting no use out of making it `async` or `await`ing it.

Comment: That's neat and efficient. Work really well, Goes from 0.1.2 - prints table - prints "ALL DONE". Thank you.